# Docker Network Setting

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have installed docker on my CentOS machine. I would like to do my Continuous Deployment with my installed docker. I have Gitlab to run CI/CD. I want to deploy my code into my docker. But, I cannot find my docker network. What port should I use ? I have public IP for my machine.

Thank You

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Running containers are by default completely isolated from the host os. If you want to expose something that runs in a container you need to map a port from the container to the host.

This can be done using the `-p` option with `docker run` or using a `ports` section with `docker-compose`.

For example:

```
docker run -p 80:80 nginx
```

.. visit your host at port 80 and you'll see the nginx welcome page.

If you are planning to run multiple containers running http(s) you need one container acting as a reverse proxy forwarding requests to right container using virtual hosts.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But, what I want to achieve is that my Gitlab can deploy image to my docker, but I cannot find any port or connection to connect my Gitlab into my Docker. Any idea ? thanks

Comment: Configure socket https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option